# Disable conversion from char* to java.lang.String

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, swig

on C side I have something like

```
void fn(char *s) {
  if(s != NULL) {
    sprintf(s, "some string");
  }
}
```

I want to get the value on java side using `carrays.i` SWIG module. But SWIG generates for me somthing like `fn(String s)`. How to prevent such conversion to have something like `fn(char_p s)` to use `carrays` functionality.

Comment: Sometimes tools do things the way they do things; have you tried `void fn(char s[])`?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch produces the same `java.lang.String`

Comment: The docs say that `carrays.i` is for treating a C pointer as a Java array and `signed char` won't be mapped to `String`. So, `void fn(signed char *INOUT)` gives you `public final static native void fn(byte[] jarg1)`.

Comment: @TomBlodget this option works for me. Pity I'd need to modify code on C-side.

Comment: You just need to do in your %module file.

Comment: @TomBlodget wow , can you post it as an answer ? I'd like to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The docs say that carrays.i is for treating a C pointer as a Java array. Also, `signed char` won't be mapped to `String`. So, `void fn(signed char *INOUT)` gives you `public final static native void fn(byte[] jarg1)`

You override your C declaration (probably in a C header file) within the module .i file:

```
%module test
%include "typemaps.i"
%include "carrays.i"

%{
extern void fn(char *);
%}
extern void fn(signed char *INOUT);
```

Comment: I'm getting compilation error in my `test_JAVA_wrap.cpp`

`test_JAVA_wrap.cpp: In function ‘void Java_com_jni_test_fn_1_1SWIG_10(JNIEnv*, jclass, jbyteArray)’:
    test_JAVA_wrap.cpp:597:10: error: invalid conversion from ‘signed char*’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]`

I don't want to change auto-generated file. Is it possible to tell SWIG to use proper type?